How can magic believably evolve in an alternate evolution scenario?
Perhaps the only time magic has been implemented in an otherwise grounded speculative evolution setting is Kaimere, and that has been appropriated into just an exonym for "sapient germs in an alien planet". This is in the context of a seedworld, the process of colonizing extraterrestrial worlds with Earth organisms. But what about alternate evolution, the process of choosing one geologic time period on the actual Earth, tweaking it one way or another and then just running with it?
For specificity's sake, let's narrow down the magic to just the following aspects:

Transformation into another animal (similar to the Rowlingverse's animagus)
Elemental manipulation (think how bending works in Avatar)

These two, I think, don't require incantations or nonliving vessels (like a wooden staff), as that would be way too difficult--or at least take way too long--to explain against a spec evo backdrop. So other than sophonts developing symbiotic relationships with sapient microbes (if that's even possible on Earth), how can magic evolve in a non-fantasy, speculative evolution, alternate Earth scenario?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Voting to close. Questions that it would take a novel to answer are out of scope for this stack.

[Ponders] Umm.. hang on.. are you asking about magic itself 'evolving' like it's some kind of living creature? or for the evolution of animals in a world where magic is a real resource like air or water that they can use and exploit? because on a reread it seems somewhat unclear.. if it's the first then your asking for a freeform discussion to help develop some sort of 'philosophical' construct and the question should be closed as entirely opinion based, failing the book test and off topic for the site because it's something entirely up to the author and I should VTC.. please clarify?

"Please clarify" You've had more than a day to do that now, I'll give it another day and if you still haven't by then I feel I should add my VTC on the grounds of lacking clarity or detail.

Using the words of one of the greatest science fiction writers, Arthur C. Clarke:

Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic

Thus the apparent magic can just the the effect of a kind of advanced technology, especially bio-technology. Possibly you can send hordes of microscopic agents (programmable, remote-controllable microbes via light? some scents? chemicals?) to do the bidding and change elements. Living organisms might be more tricky, but in the end any living organism is a very well balanced self-organizing system of cells. If one can master their communications and interaction and design their DNA - many things might become possible, even morphing - who knows? Just think of natural examples of these kind of things how parasites can totally change the behaviour (e.g. this) of their hosts or species even their own (e.g. a butterfly, developing from a caterpilar to a pupa to a butterfly) etc.
Having control there might be as unimaginable for us today - just as might be unimaginable the working of a smartphone, computer or even a just a light switch or TV remote control for a person living 200 years ago or earlier. "Advanced technology" has the charm that it needs no special change to the universe or anything - just a time or circumstance when some knowledge and the ability to reproduce the technology to create the visible parts has been lost to at least part of the population (or was never discovered yet by humans as some alien technology level is superior to ours). Read the books of Erich von Däniken and you will read that most creation myths and holy texts are just a faint memory of humankind of an encounter with aliens or an advanced civilisation thousands of years ago.

It can't. Magic violates physic laws that we normally observe. For it to exist the laws must be breakable. Which means environment completely different from ours and, correspondingly, completely different evolution path.
I would give up on evolution if you want to play with magic. Magic is "discovered" by people. It is not norm, it is a deviation.
If you want it to be somewhat sci-fi and scientifically plausible imagine alien race (or even humans eventually) that advanced far beyond what we have. Their science is magic for us. Laws of physics we know now are just one of possible solutions of the equations that describe nature.
They, theoretically, can manufacture animals that have magic capabilities, release them into the wild and go on their merry way to do something else.

Magic needs not break any laws. In some fiction magic is additional "hidden" rules of the universe. Often described as a "vending machine" - you do the correct actions (the right words and gestures) and magic "happens". You get some pre-determined effect, like a pre-determined item from a vending machine. There are variations around that theme but point being "magic = not laws of the universe" is hardly universal. In D&D magic is part of the physical laws of the universe. In the Dresden Files, the main character often runs calculations for spells because magic is a scientific field.
